# How should one use “awesome” today?

Tags: slang, language-evolution, hyperbole

Lately I have been hearing the word *awesome* used in many places.  I'm trying to figure out how it is used. It has already been discussed on this site a bit.  See

- ["When I'm sad, I stop being sad and be awesome instead"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104679/when-im-sad-i-stop-being-sad-and-be-awesome-instead)
- ["Awesome" vs. "Awful"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6802/awesome-vs-awful)

---

[Wordnet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=awesome) says "inspiring awe or admiration or wonder" and gives a few examples:

> "New York is an amazing city";
>   "the Grand Canyon is an awe-inspiring
>   sight";
>   "the awesome complexity of the universe";
>   "this sea, whose
>   gently awful stirrings seem to speak of some hidden soul beneath"-
>   Melville;
>   "Westminster Hall's awing majesty, so vast, so high, so
>   silent"

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/awesome) says "expressive of awe; inspiring of awe; terrific, extraordinary"

Urban dictionary gives more definitions of [awesome](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=awesome) (see also [awesomeness](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=awesomeness)):

- Something Americans use to describe everything.
- formidable, amazing, heart-stirring, wonderful
- A 'sticking plaster' word used by Americans to cover over the huge gaps in their vocabulary. It is one the three words which make up most American sentances.
- An overused adjective intended to denote something as "cool" or "great" but instead winds up meaning "lame." This is actually a reflection of the lameness of person using the word, the degree of which is directly proportionate to difference between the user's perspective of the so-called awesome object / person / situation and that of a reasonably sober, well-informed observer.
- You

Examples themselves are awesome:

"Bono is awesome." 
"This pizza is awesome" (when the pizza in question comes from a food court at the airport)
Veronica Mars fans are awesome. They love the show so much they hired a plane to fly a message over Hollywood to show their support for renewal.

We can watch [AwesomenessTV](http://www.youtube.com/user/AwesomenessTV) or read motivational calendars:

[image]

The [world's longest waterslide](http://photoblog.nbcnews.com/_news/2013/02/22/17061729-650m-of-awesomeness-worlds-longest-waterslide-in-auckland) (Auckland, NZ) is awesome.  There is a blog [1000 Awesome Things](http://1000awesomethings.com/):

> #821 When the public bathroom has paper towel instead of hand dryers
>
> #822 When there’s still time left in the parking meter when you pull up
>
> #823 When you find out what was making that horrible smell and get rid of it
>
> #824 Finding the TV remote after looking forever

More examples at [The Book of Awesome](http://1000awesomethings.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/the-book-of-awesome-first-20-pages.pdf). The [Awesome Foundation](http://www.awesomefoundation.org/) is giving $1000 grants, to projects that it likes

So, how is "awesome" being used today?  In contrast to [cool](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cool).

Was there anything particularly awe-inspiring about these projects?  Sometimes it's serious and sometimes it's sarcastic.  My guess is it has to do with being extraordinarily good or extraordinarily bad in some way.

---

Possibly related:

[What makes "like" and "so" popular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24633/what-makes-like-and-so-popular)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What word describes our habit to use extremes in language, and what are its implications?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64754/what-word-describes-our-habit-to-use-extremes-in-language-and-what-are-its-impl)

Comment: definitely related. is this just hyperbole?

Comment: ‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪‪Epic peeve.

Comment: Only old people (GenY and beyond) use 'Awesome'; it is so 'last century'. The kidses these days use 'sweet' (or 'suh-weet' because of the difficulty of pronouncing the consonant cluster), or 'sick' (like 'bad' for 'good'), or 'poonay' (kind of a minced oath). I'd make this a real answer but I don't have time for the references.

Comment: "Man, how awesome is it that we found a parking space" is totally, like, a different word than in "The size of the universe is truly awesome." The former means *nice*, and the latter means *amazeballs*. Got it, dude? Awesomesauce.

Comment: I can use it in a sentence.  "You can suck my amazeballs."